# "rvest" not fetching the product details using html_nodes()

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest, xml2

I was using rvest for **scraping** the details of the product (Names, Price, and Availability) on amazon's product search [results](https://www.amazon.in/s?k=Smartphone&rh=n%3A1389401031&ref=nb_sb_noss). I was able to fetch the webpage with `read_html()`, but I am not able to fetch the details of the product (Names, Price, and Availability). The page has `<span>` tag with class as `class = "a-size-medium a-color-base a-text-normal"`. I have used `html_nodes("span.a-size-medium a-color-base a-text-normal")`, but got `NA`.

Here is the reproducible code:

```
library(rvest)
library(xml2)

url <- "https://www.amazon.in/s?k=Smartphone&rh=n%3A1389401031&ref=nb_sb_noss"

page <- read_html(url)

data <- page%>%
  html_node("span.a-size-medium a-color-base a-text-normal") %>%
  html_text()

print(data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to change the css selector a little bit. I was able to get the names and the prices, the availability was a little bit trickier :/

```
library(rvest)
library(xml2)

url <- "https://www.amazon.in/s?k=Smartphone&rh=n%3A1389401031&ref=nb_sb_noss"

page <- read_html(url)

name <- page %>% html_nodes(".a-size-medium.a-color-base.a-text-normal") %>% html_text()

price <- page %>% html_nodes(".a-price-whole") %>% html_text()
```

Comment: Thanks for the corrections! I will look for the availability and will update the results.